# GridView showing FAST results and inline editing items

Tags: fast-search, gridview

I'm in the following scenario: I have a single custom list coupled with a document library (for the 'attachments'). Search on this list and the attachments is done by FAST Search. All search results should be shown in a gridview, showing part of the columns of my custom list.
To make things more complex, I would like to edit the existing SharePoint listitems in this gridview, like you would edit them in Datasheet View.

Is there any control (builtin or 3rd party) that makes this possible?

EDIT: inline editing is a must, we can't use the EditForm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to deal with the display of the results. You will most likely be using a CoreResultsWebPart to display the output of the search; this has an Xsl property which can be used to style the results in the style desired. Using this you can make the results appear as a GridView.

However, there is no builtin control that will allow you to edit items directly from the results. You would either need to create a custom web part derived from CoreResultsWebPart or redirect the user to EditForm.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We'll use jQuery and the client object model to edit inline.